# Installing C# VSTO Excel addin in enterprise environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vsto, excel-addins, installshield-le

I have built a C# Excel addin in VS2012, and have no problem installing the addin on my local machine using "Publish" with a test certificate. The problem is once I try to get the addin installed on another machine on the estate I run into a host of issues. Mainly around trust issues.

I have tried three methods to get the installation to work.
1) Installing via the Setup.exe that is created when you "publish" the addin.
2) Installing using a custom setup created by the aweful partially implemented Installshield 2013 LE that comes with VS2012
3) Via silent install using a silent install using the VSTO installer using `"%commonprogramfiles%\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /I  "C:\Program Files\MyShineyNewAddin\MyShineyNewAddin.vsto"`

Ideally we need the install to be silent as all installs are deployed using the Zenworks Novel Application Launcher.

Has any one else had these issues but managed to find a solution that works? Any help or suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Duane.

Comment: Have you tried using another certificate, like one from your company or a certificate authority?

Comment: I haven't yet. I have now asked for one to be provided, and will report back once that has been supplied. Thank you, @ZippyV.